# How to add a dynamic add background-image in knockoutjs binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to bind the `li` elements

as per following :

```
<ul class="grid" data-bind="foreach: articledashboard">
    <li data-bind="style: { background-image: url(AuthorImage)}">
        <label data-bind="attr: { title: Title }, text: Title"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My requirement is to set background image of `li` element, but my code is not working

Can you give me correct syntax?

Comment: need to quote it like 'background-image' or use 'backgroundImage', take a look at the last section of docs here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backgroundImage` instead of `background-image`, and set the value as a string:

```
<li data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(' + AuthorImage() + ')'}">
```

See the **[documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)**

**Edit:**

As [RP Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer) pointed out, you can also use `'background-image'`:

```
<li data-bind="style: { 'background-image': 'url(' + AuthorImage() + ')'}">
```

Note that this supposes that `AuthorImage` is an observable. If it is not, use `AuthorImage`.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: url is not defined;
Bindings value: style: { backgroundImage: url(AuthorImage) }

Comment: @vir Try { 'background-image': 'url(' + AuthorImage() + ')'}

Comment: { 'background-image': 'url(' + AuthorImage + ')'} <== work for me ! thanks, "AuthorImage" dont need "()"

Comment: @vir Cool. Is it not an observable?

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;"  
    data-bind='style:{ background: "url(" + image_url() + ") center/cover"} '
></div>
```

js:

```
<script>
    function ViewModel(){
        var self = this;
        self.image_url = ko.observable("");
    }
</script>
```